# Jumps of a given compound Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let $Q_{1}\left(t\right)=\sum_{i_{1}=1}^{N_{1}\left(t\right)}Y_{i_{1}}^{\left(1\right)}, Q_{2}\left(t\right)=\sum_{i_{2}=1}^{N_{2}\left(t\right)}Y_{i_{2}}^{\left(2\right)},\ldots,Q_{n}\left(t\right)=\sum_{i_{n}=1}^{N_{n}\left(t\right)}Y_{i_{n}}^{\left(n\right)}$ be independent compound Poisson-processes. Here $Y_{i_{j}}^{\left(j\right)}$ are different (or at least they can be different) distributed independent random variables, and they are independent from the $N_{j}$ Poisson processes as well. $N_{j}$ processes are also independent from each other. (Basically, everything is independent from each other.) Let me denote the sum of these compound Poisson processes as

$$Q\left(t\right)=Q_{1}\left(t\right)+Q_{2}\left(t\right)+\ldots+Q_{n}\left(t\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{N\left(t\right)}Y_{i},$$

where I know the sum is also a compound Poisson-process. I know in this general case, to determine the distribution of $Q\left(t\right)$ it is a standard method to use charachteristic/moment generating functions and after it to use some kind of inverse transformation, but do we know anything about the distribution of $Y_{i}$?

My conjecture is the following:

$$Y_{i}\overset{d}{=}\chi_{1}\cdot Y_{i_{1}}^{\left(1\right)}+\chi_{2}\cdot Y_{i_{2}}^{\left(2\right)}+\ldots+\chi_{n}\cdot Y_{i_{n}}^{\left(n\right)},$$

where $\chi_{j}$ are indicators. $\chi_{j}=1$ if the examined jump of $Q\left(t\right)$ is $Y_{i_{j}}^{\left(j\right)}$ and $0$ otherwise. I think if $N_{1},N_{2},\ldots,N_{n}$ have intensity parameters $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\ldots,\lambda_{n}$ respectively, then the $p_{j}$ parameters of $\chi_{j}$s are

$$p_{1}=\frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}+\ldots+\lambda_{n}},p_{2}=\frac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}+\ldots+\lambda_{n}},\ldots,p_{n}=\frac{\lambda_{n}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}+\ldots+\lambda_{n}}.$$

I have this conjecture, because if $\mu_{j}>\mu_{k}$ $j\neq k$, then $Y_{i_{j}}^{\left(j\right)}$ will occure more often, then $Y_{i_{k}}^{\left(k\right)}$, and I think the $\mu$ parameters are additive. If this conjecture was true, then from this point it would be easier to determine the distribution of $Y_{i}$.

Do you think is it true? Is there any case, when we have a closed form for the charachteristic function/PDF/CDF of $Y_{i}$?

Comment: You have not defined $N(t)$ or $Y_i$, though I would guess that $N(t)= \sum_{j=1}^n N_j(t)$ and that $Y_i$ is your conjecture.  If so, then your conjecture is actually the definition. $N(t)$ would have a Poisson distribution with parameter $\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb E[N_j(t)]$   If all the $Y_{i_j}$ are identically distributed as well as being independent, then finding a closed form for the distribution of $Q(t)$ should be no harder than for $Q_i(t)$.

Comment: For *any* choice of i.d.d. $Y_i$ and an ordinary Poisson process $N_t$ the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{N_t}Y_i$ is by definition a [compound Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_process). The question is therefore odd. From what information do you want to back out the distribution of $Y_i$?